# QT Запись ячейки из qtableview в базу данных mysql

Tags: c++, sql, qt

[image: скрин]

Суть в том, что при выборе строки в поле "Продукция" и нажатии на кнопку "Изготовить" нужно считать ячейку с наименованием из строки и записать в таблицу "Готовая продукция" базы данных. Также другой колонкой в ту же запись идет текущая дата. В общем попробовал сделать так, но ничего не происходит. Для примера добавил в таблицу "Готовая продукция" как должно выглядеть.

```
void Pekarnya::on_make_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    finModel=new QSqlTableModel;
    finModel->setTable("gotovaya");

    if(index.isValid())
    {
        QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
        QString str = date.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");

        QSqlRecord rec=prodModel->record(index.row());
        QString id=rec.value("prodname").toString();

        int row = finModel->rowCount(QModelIndex());
        finModel->insertRow(row);

        QModelIndex aCol = finModel->index(row, 0);
        QModelIndex bCol = finModel->index(row, 1);

        finModel->setData(aCol, id);
        finModel->setData(bCol, str);
    }
    finModel->select();
}
```

Попробовал так же:

```
QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
QString str = date.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");

QSqlRecord rec=prodModel->record(index.row());
QString id=rec.value("prodname").toString();

QSqlQuery query;
   query.prepare("INSERT INTO gotovaya (prodname, date) "
          "VALUES (:prodname, :date)");
   query.bindValue(":prodname", id);
   query.bindValue(":date", str);
   query.exec();
```

тут тоже ничего не происходит

Поправил код до такого:

```
void Pekarnya::on_make_clicked()
{
    QModelIndex index;
    if(index.isValid())
    {

        QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
        QString str = date.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");

        QSqlRecord rec=prodModel->record(index.row());
        QString id=rec.value("prodname").toString();

        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO gotovaya (prodname, date) "
          "VALUES (:prodname, :date)");
        query.bindValue(":prodname", id);
        query.bindValue(":date", str);
        query.exec();

        qDebug() << query.lastError();
        qDebug() << id;
    }
}
```

Запись в базу происходит, но первый столбец пуст, вопрос остался только в том, как мне получить ячейку выбранной строки?

Реализовал так:

```
void Pekarnya::on_make_clicked()
{
    int u = ui->prodView->currentIndex().row();
    QModelIndex myIndex;
    myIndex = ui->prodView->model()->index( u, 1, QModelIndex());
    QVariant myData = ui->prodView->model()->data(myIndex);
    QString z = myData.toString();

    QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
    QString str = date.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO gotovaya (prodname, date) "
          "VALUES (:prodname, :date)");
    query.bindValue(":prodname", z);
    query.bindValue(":date", str);
    query.exec();
}
```

Все работает

Comment: А модель "Изготовленная продукция" вы обновляете? Также, каков результат query.prepare() и query.exec()?

Comment: Дело не в обновлении записи в окне, это я сделать могу. Мне нужно главное занести запись в базу, чего сделать не получается. Насчет результата не знаю, но в базу ничего не добавляется.

Comment: Так узнайте результат! С помощью отладчика например. Подключение к базе у вас [по-умолчанию создано или с именем](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#details)?

Comment: И еще, что с самим мускулом, как база создана и настроена? Попробуйте в нее напрямую из консоли записи [подобавлять](http://www.spravkaweb.ru/mysql/sql/insert).

Comment: Подключение есть, т.к. я в другие таблицы добавляю записи, только там не беру данные из tableview, а в эту таблицу я добавляю записи напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

А как ваше view "Готовая продукция" связанно с моделью finModel? Вы создаете модель, но не устанавливаете ее в качестве модели представления.

```
finModel = new QSqlTableModel;
finModel->setTable("gotovaya");
finModel->select();

QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(finModel);
```

Comment: дело не в view, мне просто надо занести запись в базу

Comment: Посмотрите, что возвращает qDebug() << query.lastError(); возможно используемый драйвер базы не поддерживает prepared. Проверить это можно с помощью bool QSqlDriver::hasFeature(DriverFeature feature) const;

Comment: Хорошо, а куда вставить qDebug? В слот кнопки или в конструктор? При вставке в слот ничего не выводит, в конструкторе - QSqlError(-1, "", "")

Comment: Сразу после вызова query.exec().

Comment: Ну вот что выводит собственно QSqlError(-1, "", "")

Answer (score 0):

Входные данные, два виджета, вероятно - `QTableView`:

```
ui->prodView;
ui->finView;
```

Для обоих из них установлены модели таблиц:

```
QSqlTableModel *prod_model = new QSqlTableModel(this);
prod_model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
prod_model->setTable("products"); // Названия не нашёл, своё подставьте.
prod_model->select();
ui->prodView->setModel(prod_model);

QSqlTableModel *fin_model = new QSqlTableModel(this);
fin_model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
fin_model->setTable("gotovaya");
fin_model->select();
ui->finView->setModel(fin_model);
```

Собственно слот, который по клику или иному событию должен быть соединён с соответствующим сигналом:

```
void Pekarnya::on_make_clicked(const QModelIndex &index) {
    if(index.isValid() == false) return;

    QSqlTableModel *src_model
        = qobject_cast<QSqlTableModel*>(ui->prodView->model());
    QSqlTableModel *dst_model
        = qobject_cast<QSqlTableModel*>(ui->finView->model());

    // Паранойя.
    if(src_model == Q_NULLPTR || dst_model == Q_NULLPTR) return;

    const QVariant prodname
        = src_model->data(src_model->index(index.row()
            , src_model->fieldIndex("prodname")));

    const int row = dst_model->rowCount();
    dst_model->insertRow(row);

    dst_model->setData(dst_model->index(row
        , dst_model->fieldIndex("prodname"))
        , prodname);
    dst_model->setData(dst_model->index(row
        , dst_model->fieldIndex("date"))
        , QDate::currentDate());

    dst_model->submitAll();
}
```

Comment: finView у меня находится на другом виджете, я не смогу к нему обратиться из виджета с prodView

Comment: Для установки данных в приведённом слоте используется модель `fin_model`. Что же мешает Вам в `finView` (или в том виджете, где тот находится) сделать метод, возвращающий указатель на модель? Если использование модели для установки данных не нравится, то можно просто читать данные из `prod_model`, а вставлять sql-запросом в `fin_model`. Как получить данные из ячейки, я в листинге показал.

Comment: Сделал, как Вы описали, но так ничего и не берет из ячейки, дебагер пишет: QSqlError(1048, "QMYSQL3: Unable to execute statement", "Column 'prodname' cannot be null") 
""

Comment: еще если делать void Pekarnya::on_make_clicked(const QModelIndex &index), то выводит: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_make_clicked(QModelIndex) и ничего вообще не добавляет

Comment: @ЛеонтийКопытов Так а `on_make_clicked` вообще вызывается?

Comment: "Column 'prodname' cannot be null" - это из-за того, что в `fin_model` не обнаружена колонка с таким наименованием. Причин этому может быть множество, например, потому что в этой модели она называется иначе.

Comment: Что касаемо подключения слота `on_make_clicked()`, то именно с этим Вам нужно разобраться прежде всего. Понаставьте `qDebug()` в каждой строке или пройдитесь отладчиком, чтобы хотя бы знать, вызывается ли слот.

Comment: Все-таки он брал пустое значение. Так и не понял почему, но у on_make_clicked() в скобках должно быть пусто, поэтому индекс пришлось завести уже в обработчике.

Comment: Если слот к сигналу кнопки подключали, то разумеется без аргументов слот должен быть.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж вы используете QSqlTableModel не лучше ли добавлять данные в базу через модель? Что то вроде:

```
QSqlRecord rec = prodModel->record(index.row());
QString name = rec.value("prodname").toString();
QString date = date.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");

QSqlRecord newRecord = record();

newRecord.setValue( 0, name);
newRecord.setValue( 1, date);

insertRecord(-1,newRecord); //add to end

database().transaction();

if (submitAll()) {
     database().commit();
} else {
     database().rollback();
}
```